# Difference between removeChild() and unlink() and why should I use them?

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

I am currently learning all about XML through Python. Python has an extra method in its DOM implementation (minidom) you can call on any Node: [`unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.unlink).
Why is it useful and what does it actually do?

I have read the definition, but I still don´t understand it and don´t know why it is recommended to be used in combination with [`removeChild()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.removeChild).

Doesn´t it have the same effect?: Removing the particular node from your DOM?